# ASP.NET MVC - Get Id from a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC and i have a problem. I needed to get a string "Category" from a dropdownlist, that was my code:

```
var CList = new List<string>();

StreetFooder sf = db.StreetFooders.Single(s => s.User.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name);

var Cqry = from d in db.Categories
where !d.IsDeleted && d.StreetFooder.Id == sf.Id
orderby d.Name
select d.Name;

CList.AddRange(Cqry.Distinct());
ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(CList);
```

And the view:

```
<div class="col-md-10">

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryList, new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

And that worked for me. After that, i realized i made a mistake and changed my string Category attribute in:

```
public virtual Categories Type { get; set; }
```

Now i want to save on my db the ID instead of string, but still want to see my string when select from dropdown list...but don't know how.

Comment: How you want to get Id, by submit or JS?

Comment: instead of List<string>() for ci list use keyvalue pair list and then just go as you are doing now

Comment: You are only passing `Name` from your `Categories`, you need also to pass `Id` to `DropDownList`.

Comment: By submit if possible, but if you want explain me how to use JS too i really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cqry = from d in db.Categories
           where !d.IsDeleted && d.StreetFooder.Id == sf.Id
           orderby d.Name
           select new { Id = d.StreetFooder.Id, Value = d.Name};

ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(cqry.Distinct(), "Id", "Value");
```

You need to also define `Id` and pass it to your `DropDownList`. This will initialize a new instance of the `SelectList` class by using the specified items for the list(`cquery`), the data value field(`Id`), and the data text field(`Value`) and add to you `ViewBag` then bind it to `DropDownList`.

You can use it on View like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryList ", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

`cqry.Distinct()` will work if you have duplicates on result, which means that the `Id` and `Value` in collection are same, if you need to distinct only by name, you need to use `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectListItem` to create the SelectList, there you can specify `Value` = your id and `Text` = display text

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx

```
var CList = new List<SelectListItem>();

StreetFooder sf = db.StreetFooders.Single(s => s.User.UserName == this.User.Identity.Name);

var Cqry = from d in db.Categories
where !d.IsDeleted && d.StreetFooder.Id == sf.Id
orderby d.Name
select d;

CList.AddRange(Cqry.Distinct().Select(x => new SelectListItem 
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Text = d.Name
}));
ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(CList);
```

You can even omit using the `SelectList` and simply pass a `List<SelectListItem>` if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In selectList, you can pass from which property you want to bind dropdown `value` and `text` property.

```
 var Cqry = from d in db.Categories
    where !d.IsDeleted && d.StreetFooder.Id == sf.Id
    group d by new { names.Name } into nameGroup
    select new { Name = nameGroup.Name, Id = nameGroup.FirstOrDefault().StreetFooder.Id};


ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(Cqry,"Id","Name");
```

You were selecting `Distinct` name, so I have used here group by name.

As I've created anonymous  object with property 'Id' and `Name`. Now you can bind it in `SelectList`.